# AutoComplete with documentation in PyCharm

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm

I've been usung Eclipse for quite a long time in Java-programming.

Now, i started learning Python and switched to Pycharm. But I cannot fell in love with the highly praised AutoComplete.

Is there a way to show a brief introduction to the suggested methods like it is done in Eclipse with the standard libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Place the caret at the function of interest and press `F2` for the quick documentation. Press `shift+F2` to get to the external documentation. If these keys do not work, check your keymap-preferences and search for documentation.